# Use predict with mutate using native pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to predict a new column onto the current df within a dplyr chain. Tried:

```
library(tidyverse)

mod <- lm(price ~ x, data = diamonds)
newDF <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, mean = mean(diamonds$x)))

newDF <- newDF |> 
  mutate(prediction = predict(mod, .$x)) # object '.' not found

newDF <- newDF |> 
  mutate(\(.) prediction = predict(mod, .$x)) # `..1` must be a vector, not a function.
```

How can I reference field `x` within my dply chain like this using the native pipe?

Comment: Yep, that works. Had never heard of cur_data() before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `dplyr::cur_data` like this?

```
newDF <- newDF |> 
    mutate(prediction = predict(mod, cur_data()))
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like cur_data() was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0 and that pick() can now be used instead:

```
newDF <- newDF |> 
  mutate(prediction = predict(mod, pick(x)))
```